# php: добавить данным из БД атрибуты микроразметки

Tags: php, атрибуты, микроразметка

Второе в моей жизни "столкновение" с php сломало мой незрелый мозг гуманитария. Пытаюсь добавить в скрипт, выводящий данные из БД в html, атрибуты микроразметки, чтобы всем ячейкам нужных столбцов хтмл-таблицы присваивался соответствующий микрокласс.

Насколько я сумела понять, мне нужно добавить что-то вроде этого:

```
function setAttribute(array_column()){
    for($inn = 0; $inn < $arrayCount; $inn++){
        setAttribute('itemprop','name');
    }
}
```

Требуется еще каким-то образом определить нужный столбец...

**Подскажите, туда ли я "копаю"? 
Что нужно исправить, если код выше имеет право на существование?**
Может, конечно, совсем ерунду написала. У меня крайне фрагментарные представления о пхп.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить мою задачу. Или буду очень признательна за ссылку на мануал (оч. желательно на русском, буржуинским слабо владею).

Вообще, любое конкретное направление (ну, кроме нецензурного:), куда взор направить, дабы осуществить задуманное.

Arendach, видимо, это тот код, о котором Вы говорите?

```
foreach($html->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $tr){
if($tr->getAttribute('class')=='restop'){
    continue;
}
$tds = $tr->getElementsByTagName('td');
if($tds->item(0)->hasAttribute('colspan')){
    continue;
}
$address = explode(',',$tds->item(2)->nodeValue);
    if($stmt = $db->prepare($sql)){
        $stmt->bindValue(1,clearString($address[0]),SQLITE3_TEXT);//area
        $stmt->bindValue(2,clearString(implode(', ',array_slice($address,1))),SQLITE3_TEXT);//address
        $stmt->bindValue(3,clearString($tds->item(3)->nodeValue),SQLITE3_TEXT);//metro
        $stmt->bindValue(4,clearString($tds->item(4)->nodeValue),SQLITE3_TEXT);//floor
        $stmt->bindValue(5,intval($tds->item(1)->nodeValue),SQLITE3_INTEGER);//rooms
        $stmt->bindValue(6,clearString($tds->item(1)->nodeValue),SQLITE3_TEXT);//rooms_s
        $stmt->bindValue(7,clearString($tds->item(5)->nodeValue),SQLITE3_INTEGER);//sq_total
        $stmt->bindValue(8,clearString($tds->item(6)->nodeValue),SQLITE3_TEXT);//sq_room
        $stmt->bindValue(9,clearString($tds->item(7)->nodeValue),SQLITE3_INTEGER);//sq_kitchen
        $stmt->bindValue(10,clearString($tds->item(8)->nodeValue)=='+');//phone
        $stmt->bindValue(11,clearString($tds->item(9)->nodeValue)=='+');//furniture
        $stmt->bindValue(12,clearString($tds->item(10)->nodeValue)=='+');//fridge
        $stmt->bindValue(13,clearString($tds->item(11)->nodeValue)=='+');//st_metro
        $stmt->bindValue(14,intval($tds->item(12)->nodeValue));//price
        $stmt->bindValue(15,clearString($tds->item(13)->nodeValue),SQLITE3_TEXT);//term
        $stmt->bindValue(16,clearString(preg_replace(['/^[^,]+,/','/Взято.*$/'],'',$tds->item(16)->nodeValue)),SQLITE3_TEXT);//other
        $stmt->bindValue(17,date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));//created_at
        $stmt->execute();
        $added++;
    }
    $total_rows++;
}
```

Comment: Что за cms или фрейм? Скорее всего не туда копаете)

Comment: Никакой cms нет, сайт самописный полностью.

Comment: Manual тут: http://php.net/manual/ru/

Comment: Спасибо :) Со временем я обязательно его буду знать вдоль и поперек. Но в данный момент у меня конкретные вопросы. Поэтому и руководство желательно узкоспециализированное

Comment: Тут тяжело помочь. Потому что самопис, как и что там у вас происходит мы не сможем угадать.

Comment: Спасибо. Но, в принципе, это может сработать? Я опасаюсь, что написала полную ахинею.

Comment: Мне кажется бред.... особенно не понятно зачем там цикл.

Comment: А что разумнее использовать вместо него? Мне нужно добавить атрибут со значением каждой ячейке конкретного столбца (в хтмл-таблице)

Comment: эм, если html, то как вы рендерите данные? Т.е. где view? Где вы данные php приводите к html?

Comment: Скрипт написан фрилансером. Вместе с еще несколькими. Он вполне рабочий. Единственное, что я сейчас пытаюсь изменить, это добавить в него те самые атрибуты каждой ячейке конкретного столбца.

Comment: приведите код тот который выводит данные на экран. должно быть что-то вроде `foreach($items as $item){ echo <tr><td></td>...</tr> }`

Comment: Добавила код с циклом foreach($html->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $tr). Оно?